# Pull Device Type in DTM

Tags: javascript, web-applications, analytics, adobe-analytics

I'm trying to argue the fact as to a project needs to capture device type into an eVar/sProp. Obviously, the technology report via SiteCat will pull this information, and I can see some use for it; however, it's still requested.

The question ==

I can pull the user-agent but I need it to be more granular, other than the entire UA string - looking specifically at the device type.

I'm not able to find any information around dong this using the dynamic variable (e.g. D=device type).

Has anyone evert tried capturing this?

Comment: Adobe parses the User Agent string and has lookup tables based on those values, that you can readily find from googling. Though FYI it's impossible to get exact iOS versions because Apple doesn't provide unique User Agent info for them.

Comment: Yeah - that's what I'm finding....wasn't sure if there was some sort of trick, or a particular value that I could piggie back on to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mobile Device and Device Type, as you see it in Adobe Analytics, uses a lookup table from [DeviceAtlas](https://deviceatlas.com/) for display in reporting. The specifics on what you're looking for is exactly why DeviceAtlas exists; to map user agents into actual readable devices, which is maintained and updated by them.

Unfortunately there's no value to 'piggyback' onto - however, there's nothing stopping you from independently subscribing to DeviceAtlas's services to obtain access to that data.